# File access in C for implemenation of a protocol OPC UA

Tags: c++, c, opc, opc-ua

In OPC UA embedded stack, some libraries exist already, the task is to implement the callback functions to facilitate the server with data access capability..

For historical access, for instance, the historical data for a specific node (node_handle) is saved in a file, to read the historical data of that node, following callback functions are provided

```
UA_Status_t  UAServer_Callback_File_Open( uint32_t node_handle, uint8_t mode, uint32_t* file_handle){

}

UASErver_Callback_File_Write(uint32_t node_handle,uint32_t file_handle, UA_Byte_String_t * data)
```

The question is, how to implement this? What is the format for the file, that is suggested? `uint32_t file_handle`, does this mean, the file is like a array with the element of type `uint32_t`

In C, when I want to open a file.  we use `FILE * fopen( const char* file_name, const char * mode)`, the file is a binary file, but how this `fopen` is implemented is dependent on the kernel system

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does it suggest, the file is actually an array of type uint32_t?

Comment: Which version of the stack are you using ? The stack is only the communication protocol, I guess how it could include some I/O code... Are you maybe more using a SDK ? (Unified Automation`s one maybe ?)

Comment: yes, it is a SDK, but not from Unified Automation, it is from Matrikon OPC UA embedded stack for micro-controller programming.

Comment: How the callback is registered. Could you provide more code ? Specially the callback function...

Comment: They are registered in the library, the library is polled periodically in response to server-client activity...And the host implement the callback function in response to the call from the library..